# Multithreaded Unit Testing

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

Can anybody recommend any good books on unit testing for multitesting applications. 
 Also can anybody recommend appplications or utilities which can be used for multithreaded 
 testing, similar to the java tool ConTest (which I've not used but a friend recommended)?

Any help particularly related to C# unit testing for multithreaded apps in particularly welcome.

thanks.
 Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ported [multithreadedTC](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/multithreadedtc/overview.html) from Java to .NET and called it [TickingTest](https://github.com/donkirkby/donkirkby/tree/master/TickingTest). It doesn't have all the features of the original, but I've found it useful. The biggest thing it's missing is the ability to monitor threads that are started during the test.

Comment: I've found Microsoft Chess from their research division, which may be of some use.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I don't have Visual Studio Team System or whatever it requires.